# Does the VB6 compiler actually run the ActiveX during the Build process?

Tags: vb6

I have a legacy VB6 project that I'm compiling to an ActiveX DLL using command line switches:

```
vb6.exe /l MyProj.vbp /outdir \bin /out \bin\BuildLog.txt
```

This was working until I added some code to a user control that checks some condition in the database when it starts:

```
Private Sub UserControl_Initialize()
    ' Offending Code:
    Call tmrCheckInbox_Timer 
    tmrCheckInbox.enabled = True
    tmrBlink.enabled = True
End Sub
```

The project gives no errors and runs fine when I do a CTRL-F5, but it won't build.  If I take out the 3 lines above, it builds fine.  Note that the code above depends on some other startup code in the main module that has to run first (to setup the database connection, etc.).

Now the only way this can be causing a compile error is if this `UserControl_Initialize()` sub is actually being executed during the build process.  Does that make any sense?  Why would the compiler be doing this?

Any idea what's going on here?

**Edit**:

I can get it to compile the DLL if I move this code into a new `Start()` sub, and call the `Start()` sub from the form that uses it.  This means it *must* be calling `UserControl_Initialize` during the build process.  So I have my work-around, but I really want a definitive answer about what's going on here.

**Edit 2**:

I believe this might be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395269/why-is-an-event-firing-during-compilation-of-a-vb6-app?rq=1).  Specifically:

> Compiling the Project
>
> When the project is compiled into an
>   application or component, Visual Basic
>   loads all the form files invisibly,
>   one after another, in order to write
>   the information they contain into the
>   compiled file. A control instance gets
>   the Initialize, ReadProperties, and
>   WriteProperties events. The control's
>   property settings are compiled into
>   the finished executable.

Comment: I deleted my stupid comments. You seem to be right. But it does not make a difference that your library does not compile: if it did, you wouldn't be able to use it anyway. Because to use it, you need to reference it from another project and put a referenced user control onto your form, and at that moment your `UserControl_Initialize` will run, right under the form designer, and try to connect to the database. The right thing to do here is to detect whether or not you are running under forms designer, [e.g.](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?231468-VB-Detect-if-you-are-running-in-the-IDE).

Comment: @GSerg - true, or at least detect if the initialization code had been run, and don't make the database call if it hasn't (which is essentially the same thing).  Since `Form_Load` doesn't get called until runtime, my work-around seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Scott, I'm sure you are right about what is going on. In fact I think we should probably close your question as a duplicate of the other question that you found.